# INSTEAD OF TRIGGER for unique PK ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a `table_1` which is getting data from `table_2` through the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO database1.tbl_1 (idx, user_id, stasus_idx) 
    SELECT idx, user_id, stasus_idx  
    FROM database2.table_2 
    WHERE stasus_idx = 591
```

The `table_1` has the exact column structure as `table_2` except there is an extra column at the beginning to provide unique `ID`. So the `table_1` columns look like this:

```
ID, idx, user_id, stasus_idx
```

I have created an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_ID ON table_1
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_1 ON
   .
   . -- trigger
   .
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_1 OFF
END
```

....to insert the new unique `ID` for each row but id does not work as expected. It just inserts **1 record** and its done. I could fetch all the rows into a CURSOR and process one by one but that would be terribly inefficient.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can't you just declare `id int identity(1, 1) unique` or `id int identity(1, 1) primary key`?

Comment: That would be too easy :), the unique ID is actually present in many tables and has to be unique across all those tables. So when unique ID is inserted in one table, it increments where it left off for the next table and so on.

Comment: . . If you are using SQL Server 2012, sequences solve this problem (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx).

Comment: ..ok, that looks promissing. So if I create a sequesnce i.e.:CREATE SEQUENCE next_ID
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO

Comment: ..continuing: ..how would it implement it into the INSER INTO statement ?

Comment: Put the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_1 ON` and `OFF` around your Original statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a sequence solves your problem.  You can easily define one, using the syntax:

```
create sequence sequence_name as int start with 1 increment by 1;
```

Note that the default type is `bigint`.  And sequences seem to start at the smallest value rather than 1 by default.

You can then use these in tables, by using `default`.  Here is an example:

```
create table t1 (
  id int primary key default (next value for test),
  id2 int identity unique,
  val int
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8b51/1) is a simple SQL Fiddle illustrating them.  The documentation I referred to in the comment seems quite useful.

Comment: ..thanks, that worked. When I create the table_1 with ID column specified as (next value for sequnce_ID), all records are inserted with unique ID and when continuing in the next table the ID keeps the previous record count and starts from there. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to change your database to make use of a sequence then you should be able to use your original query without the trigger like. Just add the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` statements around your query.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT database1.tbl_1 ON;

INSERT INTO database1.tbl_1 (ID, idx, user_id, stasus_idx ) 
    SELECT ID, idx, user_id, stasus_idx  FROM database2.table_2 
    WHERE stasus_idx = 591;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT database1.tbl_1 OFF;
```

Comment: ..hi Jody, I tried your suggestion but I could not make it work across all tables. Thank you anyway.